# Django Filter Object with created_at within the last 3 hours

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, date-range

```
start_date = datetime.date(2017, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2017, 2, 28)

camera_logs = CameraLog.objects.filter(camera_id=camera_id, created_at__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

I see how to filter by days, but how might I filter by certain hour periods? I need to filter by `3, 6, 12, 24` hours.

Comment: I think you need field of `models.DateTimeField`, but not `models.DateField`

Comment: I already have them. That's what `created_at` is.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `datetime.datetime`:

```
start_date = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0) # hour 0
end_date = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 3) # hour 3
```

This would filter the values where `created_at` is between midnight and 3am.

---

To filter by the last three hours:

```
# current date with minutes, seconds, and microseconds set to 0
end_date = datetime.datetime.today().replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
# shift that date by 3 hours to get the start of the range
start_date = end_date - datetime.timedelta(hours=3)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you recommend filtering the last 3 hours... can you provide a sample of just that?

Comment: @dcolumbus Updated. You want to use `datetime.timedelta` to shift by three hours.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would get the current time, and then substract 3 hours for the range:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import datetime
import pytz


end_date = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()).replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('America/Guatemala')) 
start_date = end_date + relativedelta(hours=-3)
camera_logs = CameraLog.objects.filter(camera_id=camera_id, created_at__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

Just replace 'America/Guatemala' with your timezone.

Comment: I don't have acess to `dateutil`